# How do I handle dock icon click using Apple Carbon

Tags: macos, macos-carbon

Is there a way to handle running application dock icon click using Apple Carbon?
Found nearly nothing on web, so asking here.
Any help or code appreciated

Comment: Note to whoever voted to close as “belongs on superuser.com”: Carbon is a programming framework.

Answer (score 2):

Handle the `kAEReopenApplication` Apple Event.